# Trying to get key value pass in the proc in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an action method, called `Index_shift` inside one my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index_shift()
{
    ViewBag.shift_details = new SelectList(Getshift_details(),"ShiftId","ShiftVal");
            
    return View();
}
```

The `Getshit_details` implementation:

```
private List<shift_details> Getshift_details()
{
     List<shift_details> shift_detail = new List<shift_details>();
     shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 0, ShiftVal = "Select" });
     shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 1, ShiftVal = "A" });
     shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 2, ShiftVal = "B" });
     shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 3, ShiftVal = "C" });
     shift_detail.Add(new shift_details { ShiftId = 4, ShiftVal = "G" });
     return shift_detail;
}
```

The action is called from the following view section:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index_shift", "Scm_Mod_Sug", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <div>
      @Html.DropDownList("shift_details", ViewBag.shift_details as SelectList, new { Class = "form-control selectpicker show-tick" })

      <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
  </div>
}
```

The return value of the http method is the value, which I pass (*0, 1, 2, 3, 4*), not the shift value (*Select, A, B, C, D, G*).

The code, which communicates with the database:

```
 public ActionResult Index_shift(FormCollection form)
 {
     string shift_details = form["shift_details"];
     OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABC"].ToString());
     try
     {
         conn.Open();
         OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
         command.Connection = conn;
         command.CommandText = "pd01";
         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         command.Parameters.Add("V_SHIFT", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = shift_details;
     }
      //...
}
```

I am getting the value 1 in the shift details. I want to pass value '1' and receive 'A' in return.

Any idea how can I achieve it are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should do `ViewBag.shift_details =new SelectList(Getshift_details(),"ShiftVal","ShiftVal");`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thx a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
new  SelectList(ViewBag.shift_details, "ShiftId", "ShiftVal ")
```

Instead of

```
ViewBag.shift_details as SelectList
```