# Trying to return to same view and bind data there after posting data and binding value in asp.net mvc from same view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using FormMethod.post and for retrieving value on page and then post it.

`index_shift.cshtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index_shift", "Scm_Mod_Sug", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
    @Html.DropDownList("shift_details", ViewBag.shift_details as SelectList, new { Class = "form-control selectpicker show-tick" })
    </div>
}
```

In controller Scm_Mod_Sug

```
public ActionResult Index_shift()
{
    ViewBag.shift_details = new SelectList(Getshift_details(), "ShiftVal", "ShiftVal");
    return View();
}
```

After posting value to it want to return value to same view (`index_shift.cshtml`) and bind value on that page but I get an error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'shift_details'

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index_shift(FormCollection form)
{
    shift_details = form["shift_details"];
 
    ViewBag.Rval0 = values[0].Split('~');
    return view()
}
```

Any idea how to achieve it would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to write this code `ViewBag.shift_details =new SelectList(Getshift_details());`  in post action too.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i am returning ViewBag.Rval0  in Index_shift.cshtml  and binding a table but if page will load first time then ViewBag.Rval0 will not find in Index_shift.cshtml ,how to handle it any idea..

Comment: Because you are not setting value for `ViewBag.Rval0` during first time

Comment: where i need to set, at view side?

Comment: You need to set in `Index_shift()`

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
ViewBag.shift_details =new SelectList(Getshift_details(), "ShiftVal", "ShiftVal");
```

You are writing value two twice. Change it to this:

```
ViewBag.shift_details =new SelectList(Getshift_details(), "ShiftId", "ShiftVal");
```

You must provide Id to the SelectList.

Comment: @noobbroprogrammer it is fine please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62632108/trying-to-get-key-value-pass-in-the-proc-in-mvc/62633474#62633474

Comment: @Mohan This link has used ShifttId and ShiftVal whereas you have used ShiftVal at both the places. See my edited answer.